# Making a map with 8 different rasters of the same place but with only one legend in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend, maps

[image]

I have 8 raster images of a farm that are changing with respect to time. I want to create one map as shown in the attached image which will show the 8 raster images with only one legend to represent raster pixel values across all 8 rasters.

Comment: Provided all maps are set to the same color ramp with the same min max values, then you just put in one legend and it applies to all.

Comment: This can be easily done by the qgis map composer.

Comment: i am afraid they have different min max value .. and i dont know how to do it... ? can u tell me how can i do it

Comment: @neogeomat  how can i do it ? can i get procedure for that

Answer (score 5):

As @JoshC mentioned in the comments, the same color ramp with min and max values has to be set for all the layers.

Make a note of the minimum value across all the rasters and do the same for the maximum. Then, go to the Layer Styling of each layer and set the minimum and maximum to the values you noted.

Comment: as i am new to this kind of stuff.